# Unfortunately app has has been stop after adding an event

Tags: android, events

The issue arises *only* if I register one extra `RadioBox` event in `onCreate()`, other evens are just fine.
Perhaps there's something wrong or incompatibility issue in my event method, I'm actually a (very) beginner, so I've been searching the causes over the internet but still no luck. **Android** *version 4.4.4* , I'm using **Android Studio** & real device **Sony Xperia** for debugging.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // setContentView(text);
        setContentView(R.layout.file_layout); // load "file_layout.xml"

/*============== These 3 events are just fine============
        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnEditText();
        addListenerOnCheckBox();
======================================================*/


       addListenerOnRadioBox(); // THE PROBLEM IS THIS ONE!


    }
```

**And this the method I used to register the RadioBoxes**

```
public void addListenerOnRadioBox() {
        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this,radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

**Their layout config :**

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="male"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="female" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

I'm thinking about incorrect stuff around here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.mkyong.com.helloworld2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
....
....
</manifest>
```

Thanks before

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? It really helps in finding the error

Comment: ah I forgot that, ok wait..

Comment: Have you initialized `btnDisplay` or not???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code, I guess you haven't initialised `btnDisplay` thats why your app getting crashed. Initialise `btnDisplay`in `addListenerOnRadioBox()` method before setting `onClick()` callback.

```
public void addListenerOnRadioBox() {
        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        //Initialise button 
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDisplay);
        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                radioSexButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this,radioSexButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```